# Using get_artist_audio_features from spotifyr when artist name doesn't work

Tags: r, spotify

I am using the spotifyr package to work with spotify data. I want use get_artist_audio_features for an artist called Jelen, so I put his name into the function:

`jelen<-get_artist_audio_features('Jelen')`

It worked, but the features I received wasn't from Jelen, but Jelena Kerleusa.
Then I found Jelen's artist ID and run the code again:

`jelen<-get_artist_audio_features('2m34bLaM6TJ5Iw6TOB3ejr')`

but this time I only got an error:

```
Error in parse_url(url) : length(url) == 1 is not TRUE
In addition: Warning messages:
1: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'id'. 
2: Unknown or uninitialised column: 'name'.
```

I saw the body of the function and I think it should work.

Do you have any idea how to make it work?

Thank you

Comment: Looks like a bug report, it would be nice to create an issue on the github of the project.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me. Then I upgraded for the developer option in github and solved the problem: devtools::install_github('charlie86/spotifyr')
I hope it helps

Comment: I'll try it, thank you. But right now the spotifyr package is not working. It was removed from CRAN and I have no idea why.